# How to pass a list/array as argument to python fire?

Tags: python, python-fire

I have function like this -

```
def my_func(my_list_arg=["one", "two"]):
```

Which I'm trying to call from command line using `python-fire`.

I have tried several ways -

---

Attempt 1:

```
fire_runner.py my_func [one, two]
```

Results in two separate arguments `"[one"` and `"two]"`.

---

Attempt 2:

```
fire_runner.py my_func ["one", "two"]
```

which has the same result.

---

Attempt 3:

```
fire_runner.py my_func [\"one\", \"two\"]
```

same result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your list will first be parsed by the command line shell. This means you need to force it as a single argument. There are many ways to do this:

1. No space: `[one,two]`
2. Escape the space: `[one,\ two]`
3. Quotes: `"[one, two]"`.

Note that you could modify your function to take a list of arguments using the following syntax:

```
def my_func(*args):
```

The name `args` here is convention, but it is just a variable name, so it can be anything. This will allow you to call your function as

```
fire_runner.py my_func one two
```

Comment: Strangely, none of the 3 methods at the top seem to work for me if the argument contains a full stop. It treats the list argument like a single string again. To reproduce: `fire_runner.py my_func [one,two.two]`  (or anly of the other options)

Comment: @JamesOwers The brackets or dot might have special meaning to the shell. I suggest reading about how to escape special characters for the specific shell you are using.

Comment: Good point - i'm just using `bash`. However, given the error you'll get is: `KeyError: '[one,two.two]'`, we can deduce that the full stop is getting into the command ok. A clunky solution is to quote both the keys and the list: `fire_runner.py my_func "['one','two.two']"`

Answer (score 5):

Adding this answer just for a special case.

given that your function is like this:

```py
def my_func(dates: List[str] = []):
    ...
```

In case you need to send list of dates (or any combination of numbers and characters) from the CLI, the following **WON'T** work.

```
fire_runner.py my_func --dates 2021-09-20,
fire_runner.py my_func --dates "[2021-09-20]"
fire_runner.py my_func --dates [2021-09-20]
```

In all the above cases, dates will be read as one string instead of list of strings. For proper reading of list of strings you can use the following.

```
fire_runner.py my_func --dates "[\"2021-09-20\"]"
fire_runner.py my_func --dates "[\"2021-09-20\", \"2021-09-76\"]"
```

Comment: Please note that having an empty list (ie a mutable element) as default argument of your function is a common bad practice in python and will do you no good

Comment: @ThéoRubenach I believe it's only bad practice if you accidentally modify the mutable argument. If you are careful not to do this then I find that using `[]` is more intuitive to the use of your function than `None`. Plus it makes type hinting simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Not keeping any space after the comma worked for me.

```
fire_runner.py my_func [one,two]
```

Comment: Alternatively, try putting quotes around the list.

Answer (score 3):

Fire converts a comma-separated digit string to tuple as follows:

```
fire_runner.py my_func  1,2,3
```

and for a comma-separated string you can use:

```
fire_runner.py my_func  \'2021-2\',\'20212-3\',\'2023-4\'
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a special corner case solution for **one element lists**, as the above syntaxes did not seem to work (list was parsed as a string starting with `[` ):

`fire_runner.py my_func "['one']"`

Comment: Fantastic, it was very hard to find how to manage single element lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a list as argument, just separate the list item with comma (no space)
For example, for a file named fire_runner.py

```py
# fire_runner.py
import fire
import json
def my_func(my_list_arg=["one", "two"]):
    print(json.dumps(locals(),indent=2))
    return

fire.Fire()
```

You can pass [one,two,three,four] to the function by typing

```bash
python fire_runner.py my_func one,two,three,four
```

results

```bash
{
  "my_list_arg": [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
  ]
}
```

If you want pass one element list, ex. [one], just add a comma after the argument like this

```py
python fire_runner.py my_func one,
```

results

```bash
{
  "my_list_arg": [
    "one"
  ]
}
```